# Creating a timer with a pause function in python

Tags: python, timer

I have been helped to make a timer where if I press the space key, it restarts. I would like to edit this code so when I press the return/enter button, it pauses the timer, regardless of where the timer is (restarted, at 0, or in the middle). Of course, I don't want it to affect the rest of the code. Here is my code:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, bgcolor
bgcolor('dodgerblue')
FONT = ("Arial", 60, "normal")

strings = input("Please enter the time: ").strip().split(' ')

time = [60 ** (len(strings) - index - 1) * int(unit) for index, unit in enumerate(strings)]

seconds = -1
ticking = False
def delSec(string):
    if len(string)==1:
        return "0"+string
    else:
        return string
def tick():
    global seconds, ticking

    turtle.clear()

    if seconds < 0:
        turtle.write("TIMER DONE", align='center', font=FONT)
        ticking = False
    else:
        turtle.write(delSec(str(seconds//3600))+":"+delSec(str((seconds%3600)//60))+":"+delSec(str((seconds%60)//1)), align='center', font=FONT)
        seconds -= 1
        screen.ontimer(tick, 1000)
key = "space"
def reset():
    global seconds, ticking, key

    screen.onkey(None, key)  # Disable event handler inside handler

    seconds = sum(time)

    if not ticking:
        ticking = True
        tick()

    screen.onkey(reset, key)  # Reenable event handler

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.color('white')

reset()

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: I want it so that if the timer is paused, *I can still reset it*.

Answer (score 1):

I use key `Return` to run function which change `paused`

```
def pause():
    global paused

    paused = not paused
```

and use this `paused` to control `tick()`

```
def tick():
    global seconds, ticking

    if not paused:
        turtle.clear()

        if seconds < 0:
            turtle.write("TIMER DONE", align='center', font=FONT)
            ticking = False
            return
        else:
            turtle.write(delSec(str(seconds//3600))+":"+delSec(str((seconds%3600)//60))+":"+delSec(str((seconds%60)//1)), align='center', font=FONT)
            seconds -= 1

    screen.ontimer(tick, 1000)
```

`tick()` has to run `ontimer()` even if it paused

---

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, bgcolor

# --- functions ---

def delSec(string):
    if len(string) == 1:
        return "0" + string
    else:
        return string

def tick():
    global seconds, ticking

    if not paused:
        turtle.clear()

        if seconds < 0:
            turtle.write("TIMER DONE", align='center', font=FONT)
            ticking = False
            return
        else:
            turtle.write(delSec(str(seconds//3600))+":"+delSec(str((seconds%3600)//60))+":"+delSec(str((seconds%60)//1)), align='center', font=FONT)
            seconds -= 1

    screen.ontimer(tick, 1000)

def reset():
    global seconds, ticking, key,
    #global paused

    screen.onkey(None, key)  # Disable event handler inside handler
    screen.onkey(None, key_pause)  # Disable event handler inside handler

    seconds = sum(time)

    if not ticking:
        ticking = True
        tick()

    #paused = False

    screen.onkey(reset, key)  # Reenable event handler
    screen.onkey(pause, key_pause)  # Reenable event handler

def pause():
    global paused

    paused = not paused

# --- main ---

bgcolor('dodgerblue')
FONT = ("Arial", 60, "normal")

#strings = input("Please enter the time: ").strip().split(' ')
strings = '10'.strip().split(' ')

time = [60 ** (len(strings) - index - 1) * int(unit) for index, unit in enumerate(strings)]

seconds = -1
ticking = False
paused = False
key = "space"
key_pause = "Return"

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.color('white')

reset()

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

---

To reset text even when it paused I pause only `seconds -= 1` - so it redraw time in every loop - even if it paused - so reset can change value.

```
def tick():
    global seconds, ticking


    turtle.clear()

    if seconds < 0:
        turtle.write("TIMER DONE", align='center', font=FONT)
        ticking = False
        return
    else:
        turtle.write(delSec(str(seconds//3600))+":"+delSec(str((seconds%3600)//60))+":"+delSec(str((seconds%60)//1)), align='center', font=FONT)
        if not paused:
              seconds -= 1

    screen.ontimer(tick, 1000)
```

Comment: when you press 'space' and later unpause it then you will see it is reseted.

Comment: to update reseted clokc automatically when it paused it would need some work.

Comment: No that's fine. Thank you!

Comment: I moved `if not paused:` and now it pauses only `seconds -= 1` and it redraws text in every loop so reset can change its value - but now it blink even when it paused.